# gtm: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of undefined

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm doing some maintenance on a website however now all links on the page are not functioning. Seeing the below error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of undefined
```

Opening any link in a new tab works fine, if we remove any link's gtm event handler it works.

I'm not sure where to start debugging and finding the cause of the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please send the code in code blocks and not in pictures.

Comment: This is the code that's breaking in gtm script and not our script.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I Have the same issue. Thanks

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem as well. This only happens when I try to load GA4 but does not happen with Universal Analytics.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. i can speculate that GA4 in some cases uses common names in global variables. it was "self" in my case and i found some unscopped variable definitions with the name "self" (without a "var" or "let")  corrected them and my problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

We had this happening on our site, we discovered it was caused by [this polyfill for URLSearchParams](https://github.com/ungap/url-search-params). When it was removed, this error disappeared.

We switched to [this other polyfill](https://github.com/jerrybendy/url-search-params-polyfill) instead, which seems to play well with Google Tag Manager. Not sure if that's what causing it for everyone, but in our case that was it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).